# Getting Skype Chat Log back

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

I had Skype on my Windows 7, and it had all chat-log for Skype. Then, I faced some Issues with the OS, so I deleted it and Installed Windows 8.1. I now have Skype Desktop on my PC, but It doesn't have chat log, and I am in need of all my old chat log. Is there any way to recover all my lost chat log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual Skype conversations are stored in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Skype\username\chatsync` in a .DAT format. There is also a `main.db` under `\Skype\username\` which includes all of your Skype History.

If you deleted this folder during the reinstall, then it's likely you have lost the chatlogs.